# No SSO after changing Identity in IIS Application Pool

Tags: iis, single-sign-on, application-pool

I'm facing an issue.
I've got 2 websites (intranet) on my IIS, one for DEV & other for PROD.

For production I had to setup an AD account for my application pool used by my production website, because it has to get some AD Attributes only enabled by ACL.
The website read these attributes & return values on webpage.

I disabled anonymous authentication & enabled Windows Authentication.
I had my AD Account to the local group IIS Usr on the server.
When I'm connecting to the website, I have to enter my credentials, SSO is not working.

On the TEST website, I let for testing the default parameter for application pool identity, and I've got my SSO working.
What is the difference between the 2 identity for SSO?

Websites are the same & web.config too.

Regards

Comment: "When I'm connecting to the website" is too broad. You need to say what browser you use, which address/URL, and from which machine (the server itself or from another machine). Besides, for such issues, ask your domain administrators for help.

Comment: ^^ I'm the domain administrator....
For testing I'm using an url like "http://servername" (default port is 80) with IE.

Comment: And I'm testing from clients, because this is my final goal. It is just I don't understand why changing identity pool, cause this trouble.
I'm using an AD account which is member of server's local admin group so, no ACL issue

Comment: Things like kernel mode can lead to such issues, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amol/2010/10/29/understanding-kernel-mode-authentication-in-iis-7/ If you are the domain administrator, I assume you know how to use AD logging and Windows security event log to figure out.

Comment: No error logs.
I tried to edit kernel mode etc...nothing change.

The only thing which seems working is to create an second IIS production website with the same AD account as pool identity, and SSO works..

I really don't understand.